# Dump data to HBase table from Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I want to dump data into the HBase table from dataframe using the Spark scala code. I tried using HBaseTableCatalog.

Added following Dependencies :

shc-core-1.1.0.3.1.5.6-1.jar

hbase libraries(hbase-client.jar,hbase-common.jar,hbase-protocol.jar,hbase-server.jar,hbase-spark.jar,hbase-shaeded*.jar,htrace-core,hbase-mapreduce.jar,hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-{version}.jar)

Below is the code:

```
case class HBaseRecord(col0: String, col1: String, col2: String)
val catalog = s"""{
"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"shcExampleTable", "tableCoder":"PrimitiveType"},
"rowkey":"key",
"columns":{
"col0":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
"col1":{"cf":"cf1", "col":"col1", "type":"string"},
"col2":{"cf":"cf2", "col":"col2", "type":"string"}
}
}""".stripMargin
val AFINN = sc.textFile("hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/Input/AFINN1.txt").map(x=> x.split("\t")).map(x => HBaseRecord(x(0).toString,x(1).toString,x(2).toString))
val AFINNDF = AFINN.toDF("col0","col1","col2")
AFINNDF.createOrReplaceTempView("rating")
val DF = AFINNDF.select($"col0",$"col1",$"col2")
DF.write.options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "4")).format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").save()
```

It throws below error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableOutputFormat
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation.insert(HBaseRelation.scala:230)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.DefaultSource.createRelation(HBaseRelation.scala:65)

I already added hadoop-mapreduce*.jar still it's throwing error.
Which library is needed for TableOutputFormat?

Thanks,

Comment: Your code on how you write the DF to Hbase looks correct to me. Did you try creating a DF based on your HBaseRecord class without reading text file and creating temp view. Just to focus if writing to Hbase is fine. Maybe also add all your dependencies to the question.

Comment: I already added all the dependencies in question. Still, I didn't get which library is missing. Could you please suggest which library is missing?

Comment: While saving Spark dataframe to HBase using .save() method, it throws " Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat" error.

Comment: I have a working example on GitHub (https://github.com/michelheil/BigData/tree/master/sparkHBaseConnector) using the shc-core library in the exact same version.

Comment: Actually hbase-mapreduce.jar was missing. After adding the jar, the issue was resolved. Thanks,